# Split string per interval and append it to its corresponding array array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach

I have a string which contains multiple commas as its separator. I know how to extract each string using the `split()` function however, here's the problem. We are given a long length of string, then for each chunk separated by commas we have to assign it to its corresponding array. Like this

```
const StarWars = '1, Darth Vader, Sith, Dark Side, 2, Obi-Wan Kenobi, Jedi, Light side, etc.
```

basically we have to parse the string and assign each value to its corresponding array based on the interval where the first value is the `ID`, the second value is `Name`, the third value is `position`, and fourth value is `whether light or dark`. This interval repeats itself and I'm having a tough time classifying each chung of the string to it's corresponding array based on the interval.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import { TextField, Grid, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import React from "react";

function Input() {
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState("");
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([])
  const [id, setID] = useState([])
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([])
  const [type1, setType1] = useState([])
  const [type2, setType2] = useState([])
  

  function handleChange(event) {
    setInputData(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    allData.push(inputData)
  }

  console.log(inputData);

  return (
    <form style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Grid item container direction="row">
        <Grid item xs={11}>
          <TextField
            variant="filled"
            color="secondary"
            fullWidth
            label="Input text here"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item container xs={1} alignItems="center" justify="center">
          <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

As you can see, I haven't implemented the `split()` function yet. We have to assign each chunk of the long string to its corresponding array. The interval btw is 4. So every 4 chunks, the next chunk would get assigned to the first array, in this case `ID` Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your React code is not related to your question in any way. Even the subject is pokemon instead of startwars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.split()` with a regular expression to split at the comma before a number, map the array, and split at every comma, and use destructuring to get the values, and then return an object:

```js
const StarWars = '1, Darth Vader, Sith, Dark Side, 2, Obi-Wan Kenobi, Jedi, Light side'

const result = StarWars
  .split(/,\s+(?=[0-9]+)/) // split at every comma with spaces before a number
  .map(str => {
     const [id, name, position, side] = str.split(/,\s+/) // split at every comma with spaces
     return ({ id, name, position, side })
   })

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Once again Ori Driori Kenobi. you come to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

I would map it into an array of objects

```js
const StarWars = '1, Darth Vader, Sith, Dark Side, 2, Obi-Wan Kenobi, Jedi, Light side, 3, x, y, z';


const regex1 = /(\d+)(,[^,]+){3}(,\s|$)/g;
const regex2 = /(\d+),\s([^,]+),\s([^,]+),\s([^,]+)(,\s|$)/;
const characters = StarWars.match(regex1).map(match => { 
  const [x, id, name, position, side] = match.match(regex2);
  return { id, name, position, side };
});

console.log(characters);
```

OR

```js
const StarWars = '1, Darth Vader, Sith, Dark Side, 2, Obi-Wan Kenobi, Jedi, Light side, 3, x, y, z';


const regex1 = /(\d+)(,[^,]+){3}(,\s|$)/g;
const characters = StarWars.match(regex1).map(match => { 
  const [id, name, position, side] = match.split(/,\s/);
  return { id, name, position, side };
});

console.log(characters);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is bit late but i did it like this:

```js
let str = "1, Darth Vader, Sith, Dark Side, 2, Obi-Wan Kenobi, Jedi, Light side";

let re = /\s?(?<id>\d+)\,\s(?<name>[-\s\w]+)\,\s(?<position>[\s\w]+)\,\s(?<theme>[\s\w]+)\,?/g

let result = Array.from( str.matchAll(re),m => m.groups );

console.log(result);
```